# Transform the set of data into 5 values

Tags: sas

Suppose that I was given the following data

```
ID    Birthday          Monthly Salary   
P222  2 March 1976               9,600
P013  13 June 1955              31,450
S015  12 September 1966         27,500
```

The ID number starts with a character followed by three digits.
The first character is the abbreviation of the occupation ("P" for Professor. and "S" for Staff, etc.).

Consider the following data, denoted by (*) and (**):

(*):

```
P222   2Mar1976   9,60000
P013  13Jun1955  31,45000
S015  12Sep1966  27,50000
```

(**):

```
P222 2Mar1976  $9,6,00
***************
P013 13Jun1955 $31,450
**************
S015 12Sep1966 $27,500
***********
```

Suppose I have to write SAS programs to read the aforementioned data (*) and (**) respectively to create a temporary SAS data file, called PERSONEL, which contains five variables, namely ID, OCCUPATION, BIRTHDAY, YEAR and SALARY.

I mean YEAR by the year of birth here. So variables BIRTHDAY, YEAR and SALARY are numeric, but ID and OCCUPATION would be character variables.

For example, the first record should have

ID="P222", OCCUPATION="P", BIRTHDAY=27821, YEAR=1976, SALARY=9600

Is it possible for me to do this WITHOUT using assignment statement?

Comment: No. Why? What is wrong with an assignment statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed column text file, like your first example:

```
RULE:       ----+----1----+----2----+----3
1311        P222   2Mar1976   9,60000
1312        P013  13Jun1955  31,45000
1313        S015  12Sep1966  27,50000
```

Then you could read the variables directly from the proper columns.

```
data want;
  infile 'myfile' truncover;
  input id $ 1-4 occupation $ 1 @7 birthday date9. year 12-15 @16 salary comma12.2 ;
  format birthday date9. salary dollar12.2;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs     id     occupation     birthday    year          salary

 1     P222        P         02MAR1976    1976       $9,600.00
 2     P013        P         13JUN1955    1955      $31,450.00
 3     S015        S         12SEP1966    1966      $27,500.00
```

The second version has the values in slightly different positions and and extra line that would need to be skipped.